# Was [tag:motion] supposed to refer to Apple Motion?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Seems to ne the tag [motion](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motion) is being often misunderstood, mainly because it does not have a description. Should the tag be renamed to [apple-motion](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-motion)? This is more self evident and matches our other policy better.

If really the intention is not to be about the software Apple Motion, then the tag seems pointless. The tag [animation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation) should be more clear and should, in my opinion, be used instead.

Anybody know what the original intent was?

Comment: No idea what the intent was, but I completely agree with you.

Comment: It was meant to get you out of your chair and walking..... Actually I think it was intended for *anything* that moved -- animation, gifs, video, etc. It is kind of dead here (or was when I was more active).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good catch. I've retagged [first question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/64080/8708) to [apple-motion](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-motion) and made [motion](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motion) a synonym of [animation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation)